# grep on zipped files without zgrep

Tags: bash, grep

i need to grep on a group of files (some zipped, some not) for a particular pattern. I know zgrep can be used to grep on zipped files, but the script that is being run relies on return codes with different logic for return codes 0, 1, and anything else.

grep states:
the exit status is 0 if selected lines are found and 1 otherwise. 2 if an error occurred.

zgrep states it works the same as grep, but can handle zipped files.

however with 2 files:

```
#test1
hello
```

and

```
#test2
goodbye
```

both in the same directory

`grep "hello" *` returns 0 as expected because the pattern is found in test1

`zgrep "hello" *` however returns 1 even though the pattern was found in test1. it returns 1 because the pattern was not found in test2. turns out if any file does not match the pattern, 1 is returned, even if all other files do match the pattern.

for my case, i only care if at least 1 files matches or if no files match. if some do and some don't, that should count as a success.

so is there any way i can grep on both zipped and unzipped files without zgrep and get proper return codes since zgrep seems bugged?

grep version: 2.20

zgrep version: 1.5

note: there is no way for me or even a system admin to change these version numbers without a months long approval process, so please avoid solutions like "update your stuff"

Comment: You could try [zipgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zipgrep). It relies on `egrep` and `unzip` so it should have the same return value than `egrep`.

Comment: @Aserre zipgrep unfortunately only works on zipped files and cannot handle files that are not zipped. i need a solution that can handle both

Comment: Just as a note, [this bug was fixed back in 2006](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=190442). However you'd need to "upgrade your stuff" to version 1.3.5-14 of gzip :/

Comment: Another alternative would be to use the `-l` flag for `zgrep`, as shown in the bug report in my previous comment

Comment: @Aserre: using `zgrep --version; zgrep (gzip) 1.6; Copyright (C) 2010-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` shows the same behaviour.

Comment: @userunknown What about `gzip --version` ? On my computer, `zgrep` and `gzip` both have different version number (I'm forced to work on a mac though, so YMMV)

Comment: gzip --version is 1.6 as well, but Copyright (C) 2007, 2010, 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc. Default on Xubuntu 16.04LTS.

Comment: @Aserre gzip version is 1.5 on our systems. bug is present. looks like the -l logic was fixed, but seems the same bug exists in multiple places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `zgrep`. Try `xzgrep`.

```
$ xzgrep -q hello *; echo $?
0
$ zgrep -q hello *;echo $?
1
$ grep -q hello *;echo $?
0
```

You can also use `zcat` and `grep` together, if files are always `gzipped`.

```
$ zcat * | grep -q hello; echo $?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
zgrep -m1 -c "a23215" /var/log/syslog.*.gz | egrep -v ":0$" && echo hit || echo miss
```

shows 'miss' to me,

```
zgrep -m1 -c "23215" /var/log/syslog.*.gz | egrep -v ":0$" && echo hit || echo miss
```

while this shows 'hit', since 2 of 7 files matched.

More general:

```
zgrep -m1 -c "PATTERN" /path/FILEPATTERN* | egrep -q -v ":0$" && echo 1 || echo 0
```

will just return 0 or 1, without the filenames, which matched.